# Facebook Error. (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (username) on node type (Group)

Tags: facebook, permissions

I am attempting to pull a couple of our facebook groups into a set of feeds for our website. I have one of them working fine, but another one is producing errors. This groups is managed by a person who has been super-restrictive in his permissions settings, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it. Here is the error produced by the feed software:

An unexpected error occurred. (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (username) on node type (Group)

We have set the Facebook app settings to be public, and enabled the platform under the app settings in Facebook.

We have double checked our App ID / Secret / Page ID / Access Token and they are all correct.

Can someone help point me in the correct direction?

Thanks
Me.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the group which works has a profile ID name in my actual facebook name, but the group that does not work uses the Page ID instead (on the facebook). I don't know if that helps. thanks again

Comment: Groups have Group ID. They do not have user IDs or page IDs. And Groups does not have a field called username according to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group